# How to write a Batch Script that kills terminal sessions?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following scenario. We have our ERP Programm running on our dedicated windows terminal server, and if all the licenses get full i free them up by manually going onto the terminal server and typing the following commands in my cmd

This command gets as a list of all sessions with an session id

```
qwinsta /server:localhost
```

Output looks something like this:

```
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                  ID  STATUS 
 services                                    0  Getr.
 console           Administrator             7  Aktiv
 rdp-tcp#107       administrator             8  Aktiv
                   user1                    14  Getr.
                   user217                  12  Getr.
                   user 456                 23  Getr.
```

And with this command and the session id from above i kill the session.

```
rwinsta /server:localhost 14
```

Now since it's a tideous process i thought: Hey lets write a script and add it to Scheduler to kill all sessions everyday at midnight and since it's a dedicated server we can really kill all sessions.

I know exactly what i want to implement but can't quite figure it out technically.

I started with a rough template: (I know i doesn't make sense yet).

Explanation: Query all Sessions, Short log info about that, from all sessions get the session id and loop over the rwinsta command. When all sessions are killed short log info again.

```
all_sessions=qwinsta /server:localhost
echo "These are all Sessions ${all_sessions}"
get_session_id=all_sessions
kill_command=rwinsta /server:localhost[ID]
echo "All Sessions Killed"
pause
```

Comment: Lets try to first of all establish the facts of what you're trying to do, and whether the commands you've chosen are directly capable of doing so. This is what I read: You have a known program running on RDP, for which you'd like to free up licences, and you want to disconnect those which have been connected for twenty four hours. Does `Query Session`, _(`QWinSta`)_, show you which have been connected for a specific time? Why are you talking about querying all sessions, when you should know its `SessionName` _(I assume you would know the `TCP` number)_? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Ok so qwinsta does not show me how long the user has been connectd to but thats not a big problem here. If i just trigger the script everyday at night via scheduler let's say, it's enough.

Comment: No i don't need the sessions by it's name, just by it's ID - and thats also why i want to query all sessions at once. Forget about the older than 24h thing. I Just want to kill all session at once :)

Comment: What I'm saying is that QWinSta will show you all sessions, when you don't want them all, you only want the sessions which are relative to your problem application which requires freeing up of licences. So from what you've shown, it looks like you should be specifying the SessionName `rdp-tcp#107`. I also do not understand why you think that disconnecting someone who connected just five minutes ago would be 'enough'. Your question, methodology/flow, and task do not stack up, and until your question is completely clarified and contains the code that you have written to do it, we cannot help.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to split the lines into tokes doesn't work here, because the count of tokens isn't constant. So you need a different way to get the numbers (get the last-but-one token):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('quinsta /server:localhost ^|findstr /e "Getr." ^| findstr /v "services console"') do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do (
    if not "%%b" == "Getr." set "sID=%%b"
  )
  ECHO rwinsta /server:localhost !sID!
)
```

You may need to adapt the strings in `findstr /v` to your needs.